# Passing dynamic value in Json object

Tags: javascript, json

i am new in Json/JS, Could you help telling how to pass a a value from js var to Json object as in below case:

```
var ad_id = JSON.stringify(Adv.get({"name":"Abc"}));
console.log(ad_id);
```

O/P is correct - `{"incomplete":false,"list":[{"id":1303,"name":"Ad9023"}]}`

Now here I need to extract value of id and pass it to below command

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(As.put({"ad_id":ad_id.id,"name":"A9023"})));
```

O/P I am getting is - Response 200 received

```
{"incomplete":false,"error":[{"code":10,"jpath":"$.ad_id","message":"Val
ue cannot be null or missing."}]}
```

Comment: What are `Adv` and `As` ?

Comment: these are methods written in JS, used in JS based customised framework which works along with node js

Comment: JSON object is nothing different from actual JS object. So you need to pass `ad_id.list[0].id` instead of `ad_id.id`.

PS: This is really not a good question. You need to understand fundamentals first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want

```
var getVar = JSON.stringify(Adv.get({"name":"Abc"}));

var putVar = { "ad_id":getVar.list[0].id,"name":getVar.list[0].name};
console.log(JSON.stringify(As.put(putVar)));
```